# Mortality rates - can multiple (overlapping) categories with <20 events be combined?

Tags: categorical-data, mortality

I'm trying to track trends in alcohol/tobacco/drug related deaths for a small, rural county. I have some locally produced stats where they seem to just add the relatively few alcohol and drug related deaths (1-10/year each) to the larger number (30-50/year) of tobacco related deaths, then scale that number up to a "per 100,000" rate. Additionally, some deaths might be classified in more than one category (e.g. related to both drug and alcohol use).

Is this combining of overlapping categories a sound statistical practice? Why or why not? Would the better approach be to combine multiple years for the smaller categories?

This is the first time I'm using this forum, so please let me know if I'm violating any etiquette/norms/etc.